# Python Print color output to file. Able to read file in color when we open a file

Tags: python, python-2.7, colors

Is there any method in python to print color output to file and read the output in color when we open a file?

I am using linux oS.

I am converting output file to html using en script and read in browser.

Below is the code:

```
import sys
import time
class bcolors:
   HEADER = '\033[95m'
   OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
   OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
   WARNING = '\033[93m'
   FAIL = '\033[91m'
   ENDC = '\033[0m'
   BOLD = '\033[1m'
   UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'
from prettytable import PrettyTable
a = "ok"
b = "Failed"
t = PrettyTable([bcolors.WARNING + 'Input' + bcolors.WARNING, bcolors.WARNING + 'status' + bcolors.WARNING])
if a == "ok":
   t.add_row([bcolors.OKGREEN + 'FAN' + bcolors.ENDC, bcolors.FAIL + a + bcolors.ENDC])
else:
   t.add_row(['FAN', b])
storage_file = open("Storage-output.txt", 'w')
sys.stdout = storage_file
print t
storage_file.close()
```

It generates text file Storage_file.

I will Storage_file to convert html  using enscript . Below is the command.

```
enscript --language=html -o file_out_html.html Storage-output.txt
```

Now my output in web browser is displaying like below :

```
Storage-output.txt
+-------+--------+
| [93mInput[93m | [93mstatus[93m |
+-------+--------+
|  [92mFAN[0m  |   [91mok[0m   |
+-------+--------+
```

Requirement:

1. Since i am not writing html script. I am writing python script it generates output and send to file. I need read this file in web browser with colors.

Any solutions are fine to me

Comment: open a file in what program?

Comment: Actually I am converting this output file to html and read it in browser

Comment: It is indeed possible to render HTML with color. Can you provide more detail?

Comment: If you know how to create HTML in an editor that displays color when rendered in a browser, then clearly you can write code to generate that same HTML and save it in a file. How do you think web sites display color in  their content?

Comment: Helpers, I have provided more details

Comment: @kevin, I am not writing html code

Comment: @aryamccarthy, I am not writing html code but i am converting it using enscript

Answer (score 0):

The strings in your class `bcolors` are ANSI colour codes. If you have an appropriately configured terminal emulator, when you send this output to the screen using a `print` statement, you will see colours.

But HTML has a completely different way of specifying colours: it looks like this

```
<p style="color:red;">This is a paragraph.</p>
```

Browsers don't understand ANSI colour codes, so your `enscript` command needs to know how to translate them into HTML. But Enscript doesn't understand ANSI colour codes either. If you want to specify colours to Enscript you need something like

```
~color{red green blue}
```

where `red`, `green` and `blue` are given as decimal numbers between 0 and 1.

When you run Enscript you need to define, say, `~` as the escape character: add 
 `-e~` to your command line so that the `colour` directive will be recognized. If there is `~` in your data then choose another character.